# Saving a subscription plan with a payment

Tags: ruby, e-commerce

Is this acceptable for readability or would it be better to refactor it into smaller methods?

Tips?  Comments? Examples?

```
def save_with_payment
  if valid?
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(:amount => (self.plan.price * 100).to_i,
                                   :currency => 'usd', :card => stripe_card_token, :description => "Charge for #{user.email}")
    self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
    self.starts_at = Date.today
    self.amount = plan.price
    self.expires_at = 1.years.from_now
    save!
  end
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  logger.error "Stripe error while creating charge: #{e.message}"
  errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
  false
end
```

Comment: Is it a joke?..

Comment: @Nakilon, are you answering a deleted comment? otherwise I don't see the joke.

Comment: @tokland, I don't the complexity nor unreadability nor hugeness in this code.

Comment: I see. Well, I think the OP was just being modest, indeed it's not complex nor unreadable, but of course it can be improved (as any other code), I'll post an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes about your code:

- Indentation of a call with multi-line hash: That's subjective, but this style you use wastes a lot of space, and it's pretty hard to read (because of the longer lines). If the hash is long I prefer to use the one-line-per-key/value JSON style. More on this [here](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyIdioms#Multi-line_array/hashes).
- `self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id`: When you have a lot of sets + `save!` it is better just to use `update_attributes!`.
- `save!`: The method is named `save_with_payment`, in a ActiveRecord context that means this method won't raise an exception, so you should call `save`.
- `if valid?`: No `else` branch? The method seems to return a boolean so returning `false` in that case would be more consistent.
- `rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e`: That's a long and subjective topic. My opinion: don't wrap a whole method that is doing lots of things with a `rescue`, the logic forms now some kind of spaghetti. Wrap the specific parts of the code that may raise that particular exception.
- `Stripe::Charge.create`: You asked if the code is too complex. I don't think so, at least not compared with typical Ruby practices, but it's probably more orthodox to create a separate method for this call.
- `errors.add :base,`: I don't like this mixing of calls with parens and calls without, it looks messy. DSL-style code in Rails without parens -> ok, normal code in methods -> not so sure, I'd write them. Or at least be consistent.
- `self.plan`: It's not idiomatic to write explicit `self.` to call instance methods.

I'd write:

```
def save_with_payment
  if !valid?
    false
  elsif !(charge = create_stripe_charge)
    errors.add(:base, "There was a problem with your credit card.")
    false
  else
    update_attributes({
      :stripe_charge_id => charge.id,
      :starts_at => Date.today,
      :amount => plan.price,
      :expires_at => 1.years.from_now,
    })
  end
end

def create_stripe_charge
  Stripe::Charge.create({
    :amount => (plan.price * 100).to_i,
    :currency => 'usd', 
    :card => stripe_card_token, 
    :description => "Charge for #{user.email}",
  })
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  logger.error("Stripe error while creating charge: #{e.message}")
  nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the `Charge.create` to a separate class.

Because one the principies that we have respect is "our code reader should not read the details of the implementation for understand the code"

Comment: Please explain why you would do this. (In the meantime -1)

Comment: I would extract it to a own method, just to get rid of the long line and give it a descriptive name.

Comment: I explain it, it's my opinion

Comment: That's a good point (the answer's point, not the comment's point).